# Custom entity missing from File -> New Record menu in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: ribbon, crm, microsoft-dynamics

We have an On-Premises version of Dynamics CRM 2011. A custom entity that I created is missing from the `File -> New Record` menu. Any idea how to get it there?

I have rights to create the entity. I've been using the [Visual Ribbon Editor](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/) to hide and add some buttons on lots of different entities.